# How to list gcloud dataflow jobs filters to list only draining jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I want to get the list of the jobs that have the status "Draining"

```
# gives 0 results 
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="status=Draining"
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="status=draining"
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="Status=Draining"
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="Status=draining"

# gives an error, because status can only be "all", "active", "terminated"
gcloud dataflow jobs list --status="Draining"
```

Comment: According to [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list) the flag `STATUS` has only three options `active`, `all` and `terminated`. Can you try the  `gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter='STATE=DRAINING'` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag `STATUS` has only three options `active`, `all` and `terminated`, that is why you are getting an error in your last command.
You can follow this google cloud documentation to know more about the Status field.

To get the list of the jobs that have the are in "Draining" mode you can use bellow command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter='STATE=DRAINING'
```

[image]

Addition to @Mazlum Tosun’s answer you only need to use  `--region` if you want to have a region specific resource list.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm the @kiran-mathew comment, you can use the following `gcloud` command to list all the `Dataflow` jobs with the `draining` state :

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --region="europe-west1"  --filter='STATE=DRAINING'
```

An example of result :

| JOB_ID | NAME | TYPE | CREATION_TIME | STATE | REGION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-14_15_00_47-1012997933146788402 | job-name | Streaming | 2022-12-14 23:00:48 | Draining | europe-west1 |